# Steam wasn't opening, so I looked at another post

Tags: command-line, steam

There it said that I should edit the environmental variable in front of the Ssteam desktop application How?

I really want to be able to just click on the icon on my desktop as opposed to opening terminal every time and typing a long command. Help? *Please?*

Also, I don't know anything about coding/Linux.

Comment: Maybe this helps? [Ubuntu 16.04 Steam only runs from terminal](//askubuntu.com/q/812040)

Answer (score -1):

You could set a shortcut on your Desktop that sets the environment variable and launches Steam, it'd basically be a shortcut to the long command you put into the terminal to launch it.

Comment: How do I do that?